# XQuery: when to use data() function?

Tags: xml, xquery

I cannot undeerstand when I should use the `data()` function.
Exemple:
`$path/@name` or `$path/data(@name)`?
Sometimes when I don't put `data()` I got an error that I can fix only adding it.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, `data()` should be used when you want to extract the atomic type of a value stored in XML and defined by a schema. For example, say you have a schema that defines this element as `xs:dateTime`:

```
<my-time>2016-01-28T10:30:45.954716-06:00</my-time>
```

Calling `data()` on `<my-time>` will return an `xs:dateTime` type value.

Most of the time, however, `data()` will simply behave like `string()`. I suspect in your code there are times when you are expecting a string but returning an attribute or node. Sometimes that "just works" because of type coercion; other times, it throws an exception. This is will of course be dependent on your code.

Pay close attention to the types of nodes and atomic values in your code, and it should be a little more clear why you are getting these errors. And if what you want is a string, then use `string()` instead of `data()`.

Answer (score 4):

It's very rarely necessary to call `data()` explicitly. Almost all operations that expect atomic values can be given a node and will atomize it (that is, call `data()`) implicitly.

There are some exceptions:

- The effective boolean value of a node-sequence N is not the same as the effective boolean value of `data(N)`. For example, `if (@married)` tests whether the `@married` attribute exists, while `if (data(@married))` tests whether the typed value of the `@married` attribute is true.
- When constructing element content in XQuery, nodes are not implicitly atomized, so `<e>{@married}</e>` does something different from `<e>{data(@married)}</e>`